# Azure cognitive search unsafe/reserved characters

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I would like to ask if anyone has a problem with searching for unsafe/reserved characters? More specificaly if the string starts with, or contains only special characters, in this case #. I know it is edge case, but it seems like weird behavior. Search string is encoded in query, so it will get to the search, I know the name containing only these characters is edge case, but i am curious if it is intended behaviour or i am doing something wrong

this is the part of url containing search query `?searchMode=all&search=%23%23%23`

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? There is a documentation page that describes how you encode unsafe and reserved characters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax#encoding-unsafe-and-reserved-characters-in-urls

which is what you seem to be doing. What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: the problem is I will not get any result from the query. But I know the data is there, I can see the row with '###' as in name column when I list all data